# What is the difference between LDA 210 and LDA 212?

Tags: resistors, mains, opto-isolator, esp32

Do you see any difference between [LDA210](https://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/LDA210.pdf/$file/LDA210.pdf) and [LDA212](https://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/LDA212.pdf/$file/LDA212.pdf)? 
Can it be that a factory produces the same product with different names?

LDA210 datasheet: [link](https://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/LDA210.pdf/$file/LDA210.pdf) 
LDA212 datasheet: [link](https://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/LDA212.pdf/$file/LDA212.pdf) 
Official comparison website: [link](https://clareweb1.ixysic.com/Products/SingleDualOpto.htm) 
DigiKey comparison: [link](https://www.digikey.ch/en/products/compare?s=N4IgzCBcDaIKwDY4E4wEYQBpwAYDseCCOIAutgCxQgD0ApgHY0AOATgPYAmArgMYAuAZxoAzAJYAbfnVY12zfuzGD2EgIaLWggLT9WahoOWbtzABbtFAN1X81Y3tvbd%2BzFzWQ4wAfkEBeADkKAEkAcwArAGEAIV52SIB3AHkEgE8ARwBBAA8JTIAtUIBFBIARAE0AcV5IgFtMgMjMgAV8otK1YMyAL0yc1IBVaIBZAFFM7gBrIsyKCYGu1O4E0YpogBlMgAly6O7xgDEADjFyunDM8KKi9IBlACkJVNHbuF4%2BigTMgBVatASiutRtFUghkNElHRmgdMiAAL5AA)

**Context:** 
I am trying to sense if lights are on or off with an ESP32. I am looking into an AC optocoupler with very high CTR ratio, so that I can reduce the current (Watts) as much as possible:

[image]

I tried with the [HCPL-3700](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/HCPL3700-1010474.pdf) ([link to my project](https://github.com/crgarcia12/electronics-homeassistant-lightscontroll#version-2)), but the resistors get very hot, since I am *wasting* almost 0.6W per channel

Comment: *Do you see any difference between LDA210 and LDA212?* Yes, compare the **pin configuration**, the connections are different. I have my doubts if this is going to work propely as the **current through the LEDs** is going to be **very small**. It appears that about 300 kohm (in total so 4 x 75 kohm) would work though, see: https://smartsolutions4home.com/detecting-mains-voltage-with-microcontroller/

Comment: lol! I checked those datasheets milion times and completely missed that. Thank you!

Comment: ...  If that 300 k is still too much power usage, consider a **capacitive power supply** circuit. See BigClive on Youtube demonstrating and explaining several types: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q23uh7AjjXw

Comment: Thanks @Bimpelrekkie! I have never built a capacitive PS. I am a bit constraint in size, and when i checked for those PS they seem to need a very large capacitor. Your link is really useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pins are wired differently on the units. This is common when you want your product to be compatible with existing products, to make it easy to use your product even if you originally designed it for the competitors or an older generation of optocouplers.